# Set input value automatically on a fetch request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I present my problem to you

In the following code, I'm trying to retrieve phone numbers from an API and then show them in a Card; in each card, I have a different number which is displayed

and also in each card, I have an input field to enter the phone number which I obtained before.

My problem is that I don't want to fill in the input manually with the recovered number.

So basically I would like to start my function without having to fill in this field manually.

Do you have any idea how to do this?
I tried to simplify the code so that it is as clear as possible
Thanks for your help Neff

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { CardText, Card,Row, Col, CardTitle, Button } from 'reactstrap';
 import axios from 'axios'

 const entrypoint = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT+'/api';

 class AdminPage  extends Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        message: {
            to: '',
            body: 'hola amigo :)'
          },
          submitting: false,
          error: false
    };
    this.onHandleChange = this.onHandleChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

}

onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ submitting: true });
    fetch('/api/messages', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state.message)
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (data.success) {
          this.setState({
            error: false,
            submitting: false,
            message: {
              to: '',
              body: ''
            }
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({
            error: true,
            submitting: false
          });
        }
      });
   }
   // rest of the component
    onHandleChange(event) {
    const name = event.target.getAttribute('name');
    this.setState({
      message: { ...this.state.message, [name]: event.target.value }
    });
  }
getRandom = async () => {

    const res = await axios.get(
        entrypoint + "/alluserpls"
    )
    this.setState({ data: res.data })
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.getRandom()
}
render() {

    let datas = this.state.data.map(datass => {
       const status = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("validated-order")||"{}")[datass.id];
        return (
            <div>
              < Col sm="12" key={datass.id} className="wtfFuHereIsForOnlyBackGroundColorForCol12Nice">

           <div key="a"> 
      <Card body className="yoloCardBody">

      <CardText> Téléphone {datass.phone}</CardText>

     <form
    onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
    className={this.state.error ? 'error sms-form' : 'sms-form'}  >
        <div>
          <input
             type="tel"
             name="to"
             id="to"
             value={this.state.message.to}
        onChange={this.onHandleChange}
        /> 
        </div> 
      <Button className="buttonForLancerMaybe" type="submit" disabled= 
      {this.state.submitting}>SMS</Button>
      </form>
    </Card>
    </div>
  </Col>
            </div>
        )
    })
    return (
        <div> <div>
    <div> 
    {datas}
  </div>
    </div>
    </div>
            <div className="box">       
            </div>
        </div>
    )
    }
    }

 export default AdminPage
```

Comment: Hi, I can not find where this </Card> opening tag is located in your current code, can you edit your code (I guess sth is missing from it). So all you want is to somehow show the numbers you get in your submission's form input? right? sth like(this.state.message = datass.phone )?

Comment: @blackSheep hello , yes sorry is miss on clean code ^^i have edit , 
currently I have to enter the number in the input fields to send an SMS 
I would like to no longer have to manually fill in the famous input field in order to send an SMS automatically  thx for help

Comment: by the way, you are still missing <GridLayout> closing tag in your code

Comment: @blackSheep i have edit sorry again for miss my page is so longue for link all ^^so i have try to clean for post ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess this little change in your code will help you, separating the logic and making a new component for your form section would be your solution. say we have a component called "SmsForm" so first, you need to import it in your current component:

```
import SmsForm from "../SmsForm/Loadable";
```

and then you pass your phone number as a prop to this SmsForm like this:

```
let datas = this.state.data.map(datass => {
    const status = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("validated-order") || "{}")[datass.id];
    return (
        <div>
            < Col sm="12" key={datass.id} className="wtfFuHereIsForOnlyBackGroundColorForCol12Nice">

                <GridLayout className="GridlayoutTextOnlyForGridOuiAndHeigthbecauseHeigthWasBug" layout={layout} cols={12} rowHeight={30} width={1200}>

                    <div key="a">
                        <Card body className="yoloCardBody">

                            <CardText> Téléphone {datass.phone}</CardText>

                           <SmsForm phone={datass.phone}/>
                        </Card>
                    </div>
                </GridLayout>
            </ Col>
        </div>
    )
})
```

and SmsForm would be sth like this:

```
    import React from 'react';
     ...
    export class SmsForm extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                message: {
                    to: props.phone,
                    body: 'hola amigo :)'
                },
                submitting: false,
                error: false
            };
            this.onHandleChange = this.onHandleChange.bind(this);
            this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        }


        onSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.setState({ submitting: true });
            fetch('/api/messages', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(this.state.message)
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.success) {
                        this.setState({
                            error: false,
                            submitting: false,
                            message: {
                                to: '',
                                body: ''
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        this.setState({
                            error: true,
                            submitting: false
                        });
                    }
                });
        }
        // rest of the component
        onHandleChange(event) {
            const name = event.target.getAttribute('name');
            this.setState({
                message: { ...this.state.message, [name]: event.target.value }
            });
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <form
                    onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
                    className={this.state.error ? 'error sms-form' : 'sms-form'}  >
                    <div>
                        <input type="tel" name="to" id="to" value={datass.phone} onChange={e => this.onHandleChange(e, e.target.value)}/>
                    </div>
                    <Button className="buttonForLancerMaybe" type="submit" disabled=
                        {this.state.submitting}>SMS</Button>
                </form>
            );
        }
    }
export default SmsForm;
```

Comment: omg omg gg man it works fine thank you very much for your help